# Different behaviour of subshells and && in bash vs zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, subshell

My understanding of running commands in subshells is that the current shell is forked, and the subshell then does a further `fork` and `exec` on the desired commands.

I see strange behaviour when running the following in both bash and zsh:
`$ ( sleep 5 && sleep 6 )`

When running in **bash**:

```
$ echo $$
6410
$ ( sleep 5 && sleep 6 )
```

`ps` gives the following:
CMD: sleep 5
PID: **6590**
PPID: **6589**

and then:
CMD: sleep 6
PID: **6616**
PPID: **6589**

This all makes sense to me. `sleep 5` and `sleep 6` both have the same parent (presumably the subshell).

However, in **zsh**, I get the following:

```
$ echo $$
1987
$ ( sleep 5 && sleep 6 )
```

`ps` gives the following:
CMD: sleep 5
PID: **7576**
PPID: **7575**

and then:
CMD: sleep 6
PID: **7575**
PPID: **1987**

I can't make head or tail of why `sleep 5` has the process used to run `sleep 6` as its parent and the process used to run `sleep 6` has the original shell as its parent?

Comment: Interesting question ... note that the behavior you're seeing in `zsh` seems to meet the specification for the `(  )` operator. The `sleep` processes do not run in the first-level shell (1987 in your example), they do indeed run as subprocesses. I don't think there's a requirement that the processes have a common parent.

Comment: @Gairfowl, I don't think there's any requirement for the subshell to actually run in a different _process_ in any case. Just that it runs in a different _shell execution environment_. Sure, a simple way of doing that is to fork the process. But it's not a requirement if the shell cares to take care of it within one process.

Comment: Which is kinda why I feel like asking: Does it matter? What does it matter what the PIDs are, if the script _works correctly_?

Comment: Could be tail call optimisation. If you can not tell the difference (without looking inside the box), then it is free to optimise.

Comment: @ilkkachu - looks like your are correct, posix apparently [does not require](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) that a shell execution environment be within a self-contained process. That's going to mess up a script I wrote three companies ago that depended on a subshell being kill-able :).    I doubt the OP is worried about correct execution - my impression is that they are just trying to figure out how the world works ...

Answer (score 13):

You can get a similar thing in Bash:

```
$ echo $$
26328
$ ( /bin/sleep 1234 )
```

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,stat,args -C sleep
  PID  PPID STAT COMMAND
26473 26328 S+   /bin/sleep 1234
```

What Bash does there, is that while it does fork itself for the subshell, it recognizes there's only one command to run there, and then just exec's the `sleep` over itself as an optimization, saving the extra fork. It does the same for something like `bash -c '/bin/sleep'`

Just that Bash only does that for the case of one command, with `( true; /bin/sleep 2345 )`, you'd see the intermediate shell process too. Apparently zsh is more aggressive with that optimization and skips the fork for the last command of the list, too.

---

In any case, there's no requirement that a subshell run in another *process*. Just that it runs in another *shell execution environment*, a phrase from the [POSIX shell language specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12). Now, that environment does include things like the `umask` and the current working directory (things that are per-process on the OS level), as well as shell variables etc., so implementing separate environments via forking is the *easy* way. But it's not a requirement.

And e.g. ksh does something different, there's no fork in this simple subshell at all. But it still works, the value of `FOO` we get is from the outer shell level:

```
$ strace -etrace=clone,fork,vfork -f ksh -c 'FOO=out; ( FOO=in; true ); echo "$FOO"'
out
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Bash and zsh would fork there. Also ksh implements `sleep` as builtin, so you won't see process for it there, unless you use `/bin/sleep` explicitly.

Comment: Note that `zsh` disables that optimisation if there are traps that are defined (so `(trap "echo done" EXIT; sleep 1)` correctly outputs `done` for instance). A few shells that were also doing that optimisation failed to disable it in that case causing bugs. IIRC ksh93 still has related bugs.